# Spectral radius equality

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $A: X \rightarrow X$ be a continuous linear operator, and $X$ a Banach space. I want to prove that
\begin{equation}
r(A^n) = r(A)^n,
\end{equation}
where $r(A)$ denotes the spectral radius of $A$, that is $r(A) = \max_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} |\lambda|$. 
I know that if $p$ is a polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$, then $\sigma(p(A)) = p(\sigma(A))$. I started by writing 
\begin{equation}
r(A^n) = \max_{\lambda \in \sigma(A^n)} |\lambda| = \max_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)^n} |\lambda|,
\end{equation}
but I'm stuck here.

I was also wondering under what condition we may write $f(\max_{x \in K} |x|) = \max_{x \in K} |f(x)|$, where $K$ is, say, a compact set?  Thanks.

Comment: This is also easy if you've already established that
$$
r(A) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \|A^k\|^{1/k}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thats not necessary and is too powerful. He already has $\sigma(A^n)=\{x^n\mid x\in \sigma(A)\}$. Now $\sup_{x\in \sigma(A)}|x|^n=(\sup_{x\in\sigma(A)}|x|)^n$ since taking the $n$-th power is monoton increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact that $\sigma(p(A)) = p(\sigma(A))$, we have
$$
r(A^n) = \max_{\lambda \in \sigma(A^n)} |\lambda| = \max_{\lambda \in [\sigma(A)]^n}|\lambda|  = \max_{\mu \in |\sigma(A)|} \mu^n \overset{!}{=} \left[\max_{\mu \in |\sigma(A)|}\mu\right]^n
$$
To justify $\overset{!}{=}$, it suffices to note that

- The max is attained since $|\sigma(A)|$ is compact, which is true since $|\cdot|$ is continuous over $\Bbb C$.
- $x \mapsto x^n$ is increasing over $[0,\infty)$.  So, for any $S \subset [0,\infty)$: $\max_{x \in S}x^n = [\max_{x \in S}x]^n$.